# IDispatchEx::GetDispID returns S_OK but member can't be found

Tags: c++, internet-explorer, bho

I have the following code (where `windowDisp` is `IDispatchEx` representing a document in IE):

```
DISPID dispId = 0;
HRESULT res = windowDisp->GetDispID(objectNameStr, fdexNameEnsure, &dispId);
if (FAILED(res))
{
    LOG_ERROR("Failed creating " << AnsiConverter(objectName) << " object in "
        << AnsiConverter(url) << ", HResult: " << res);
    return false;
}
if (dispId == DISPID_UNKNOWN)
{
    LOG_ERROR("Creating " << AnsiConverter(objectName) << " object in "
        << AnsiConverter(url) << " resulted in DISPID_UNKNOWN");
}

// Validate creating property
DISPID testDispId = 0;
res = windowDisp->GetDispID(objectNameStr, 0, &testDispId);
if (FAILED(res) || dispId != testDispId)
{
    LOG_ERROR("Failed validating " << AnsiConverter(objectName) << " object in "
        << AnsiConverter(url) << ", HResult: " << res);
    if (res == DISP_E_UNKNOWNNAME)
    {
        std::string all = enumerateDispIds(windowDisp);
        LOG_ERROR("Available objects are" << all);
    }
    return false;
}
```

And (amended from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tt99ahf2(v=vs.94).aspx):

```
static std::string enumerateDispIds(const CComQIPtr<IDispatchEx>& windowDisp)
{
    HRESULT hr;
    BSTR bstrName;
    DISPID dispid;

    std::stringstream ss;

    hr = windowDisp->GetNextDispID(fdexEnumAll, DISPID_STARTENUM, &dispid);
    while (hr == S_OK)
    {
        hr = windowDisp->GetMemberName(dispid, &bstrName);

        ss << "\t" << dispid << ": " << (hr == S_OK ? AnsiConverter(bstrName) : "COULD NOT GET NAME") << std::endl;

        SysFreeString(bstrName);
        hr = windowDisp->GetNextDispID(fdexEnumAll, dispid, &dispid);
    }

    return ss.str();
}
```

My problem is that the first call to `GetDispID` returns `S_OK` and a valid dispId, which as far as I understand, means that either the member was already created before, or it got created during this call (thanks to the `fdexNameEnsure` parameter), but the second call to `GetDispID` which is supposed to validate that the member indeed exists fails with `DISP_E_UNKNOWNNAME`. When I look in the log I see all the members from the enumeration and none of them is what I tried to create. So it seems that `GetDispID` returns `S_OK` but doesn't really succeed.

I'm on Windows 10 x64 and IE 11.

The reason I'm asking is that we're getting access violations inside IE on our testing environment (Windows 7 Version 7601 SP1 x64, IE 11.0.9600.18347) with the following call stack (bottom 3 frames are ours and then we step into IE code):

```
jscript9!Js::SimpleDictionaryTypeHandlerBase<unsigned short,Js::PropertyRecord const * __ptr64,0>::HasProperty+0xb0
jscript9!Js::GlobalObject::SetExistingProperty+0x57
jscript9!Js::GlobalObject::SetProperty+0x4f
jscript9!Js::DefaultScriptOperations::DefaultOperationsWrapper<<lambda_0739649a84a512e5527a10b6eeb626fd> >+0x1b6
jscript9!Js::DefaultScriptOperations::SetProperty+0x7b
mshtml!CWindowTypeOperations::SetProperty+0x70
jscript9!Js::CustomExternalObject::SetPropertyImpl<0>+0x133
jscript9!Js::JavascriptExternalOperators::SetProperty+0xd10e6
jscript9!ScriptSite::ExternalSetProperty+0x6f
jscript9!JavascriptDispatch::InvokeOnMember+0x1fa
jscript9!JavascriptDispatch::InvokeEx+0x28e
mshtml!CBase::varInvokeEx+0xbd
Hook64!createHookObject+0x599
Hook64!InjectScript+0x402
Hook64!CHtmlInterceptor::Invoke+0x5bb
```

After getting `dispId` we call `InvokeEx`:

```
windowDisp->InvokeEx(dispId, 
    LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, 
    DISPATCH_PROPERTYPUT, 
    &params, 
    NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

And that causes the access violation. So we thought that maybe the object wasn't created...

Comment: You assume that an *added* property can always be found back without using fdexNameEnsure again.  The docs make no such promises, you have strong evidence that is not the case.  Little reason to get stuck on this, you have a valid dispid so just use it.

Comment: @HansPassant I updated the question with the reason we even tried writing this code to begin (it took me a while to reproduce). Maybe you have some ideas about the actual underlying problem...

Comment: You are adding far too much noise to this problem to ever get a usable answer.  The IDispatchEx implementation is **not** broken.  Hook64!InjectScript(), what could possibly go wrong...  Everything.  Google has one hit for CHtmlInterceptor, it is a malware analysis.

Comment: Let me assure you that I am not building malware. We are injecting a global object that is used by our script, and the end-users are perfectly aware of it. A null pointer read in `GlobalObject::SetExistingProperty` when the question is about creating a new property on the global object sounds very suspicious, and in my view points to a possible issue in the class' implementation.

Comment: If you are convinced it is an IE bug then only Microsoft Support can help you.  They'll make you provide more evidence, it isn't even clear that this code is running on the correct thread and you are not doing anything to marshal the interface pointer.  So be prepared to have a good repro available when you call for help.